# getting image from Drupal and showing in html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

I am showing image at my html page which is taken from DRUPAL side (by using ajax request)

```
$.ajax({
        url: URL + AUTH,
        type: 'post',
        data:      addItemObject(validateObject(refreshObject({"_lawyer_id":"462"})),'key','lawyerlogo'),
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            devconsole(errorThrown);
            navigator.notification.alert('Error saving data.  Please try again.', null, 'Server     Error', 'Ok');
        },
        success: function (data) {
        myalert(JSON.stringify(data["url_full"]));

        document.getElementById("lawyer_logo").src=data["url_full_mobile"];
    }
});
```

I am getting the Image URL in this format

```
http://URL/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/Jellyfish.jpg?itok=W2h3AytQ
```

I am removing the "?itok=W2h3AytQ" from URL and assigning to 'src' but it is not showing the image
how could i show the image.

Comment: ? What exactly re you trying to accomplish? You are obviously not doing it the best way with Drupal. Tell us what exactly what you want, then we maybe can help you,

Comment: Thank for your reply..actually drupal side developer has given me the JSON in response of ajax request, he got the image URL from drupal database and its running on browser at his side but this url is not showing image at my side.

Comment: Does the url show the image if you put it directly in the address bar? If not, the url is wrong.

Comment: when i am using this "?itok=W2h3AytQ" then it is showing the image..and from second time if i am not using "?itok=W2h3AytQ" in URL then also it is working..

Comment: Why do you not ask the "drupal side developer" that you are working with?

Comment: i have asked him also he is also didnt finding the solution on this problem....

Comment: A bit late I know.... but.... Your developer should be probably using drupal functions to get the correct image url, not just grabbing it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The image URL is generated by Drupal's image module, picking up the original uploaded image and generating a new one, resizing the original according to the 'image style' selected.
The "itok" query parameter has been introduced in version 7.20 to prevent random generation of new images (and blocking potential DOS attacks). https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes

Not too sure what your setup is, but probably the quickest way of getting the image would be to access the original and resizing it in CSS.
The original image URL would be:

```
http://URL/sites/default/files/Jellyfish.jpg
```

(note how you just need to remove styles/thumbnail/public and the token at the end)